# Jenkins Remote Trigger, but don't build immediately the remote build, schedule the remote build instead

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I have 2 jenkins machines: 
JenkinsA and JenkinsB.

I need a trigger in JenkinsA to trigger the execution of a project in JenkinsB. However I don't need to run remote job immediately. I need put it in queue and be able to schedule when it will run.

I also need send parameters from A to B.

Currently I am using the plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Remote+Trigger+Plugin

This plugin allows build remotely and send the parameters, but it does not allow the execution schedule in the job of Jenkins B.

Answer (score 3):

When using the build trigger and triggering the job remotely, you can append `&delay=30sec` (or any number of seconds) to the end of the build URL. This will allow the job to enter the ***quiet period*** and delay the build for the set period of time. the URL will look something like this `JENKINS_URL/job/build?token=TOKEN_NAME&delay=30sec **or** /buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN_NAME&delay=30sec`